# App first Run and NSUserDefaults, it dazzles me.

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, nsuserdefaults

I'm sure, it tells more about me as of Objective-c but I'm puzzled by the First Run check. I've read several Q&A's on this topoic but I'm not able to get it work properly.

This is the case:
In my appDelegate.m file in the applicationDidFinishLaunchingWitObjects I add the method

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if (![defaults objectForKey:@"firstRun"])
    [defaults setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"firstRun"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

In my mainViewController.m I added

```
-(void) firstRun
 {
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if([defaults objectForKey:@"firstRun"])
{
    CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [self.view addSubview:myView];
}
}
```

And at last in my viewDidLoad (in the mainViewcontroller.m file):

```
    [self firstRun];
```

I see that the view is created (blue background color) but the next time I launch the app again I'm presented by the blue-background-view. When I put my code in other places there is no UIView with blue background at all. Can anyone clears this for me, I know that I'm off track. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Side note - no need to call `synchronize` here. The only place you should call it is in the `applicationDidEnterBackground:` and `applicationWillTerminate:`.

Comment: @Maddy, thank you for your reply. I will delete the sinchronize statement. Lets look what is happening then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The blue background will be presented every time because you are adding the `"firstRun"` key into defaults before the view loads, so it's always present when the view loads and `[self firstRun]` is called.

There are a couple ways to fix this. A good solution to this is to place a Boolean property in the application delegate that you set to true during `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithObjects:` when the default has to be set. The `firstRun` method would then check the delegate's property instead of defaults to determine if this was the first run.

### Example

**Edit:** The example now refers to the user pressing an Accept button. Refer to comments.

In your AppDelegate.h file, add the following property to your interface, before `@end`.

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL firstRun;
```

In AppDelegate.m, in `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithObjects`, change your code to set the property.

```
if (![defaults objectForKey:@"firstRun"]) {
    self.firstRun = YES;
}
```

In your view controller set the firstRun value when the user presses the Accept button. This way, if the app is terminated before the user accepts, they will still receive the screen where they have to accept.

```
- (void) acceptTouched {
    ...
    if (![defaults objectForKey:@"firstRun"]) {
        [defaults setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"firstRun"];
    }
    ...
}
```

Finally, change your `firstRun` method to look at the propery instead of the defaults.

```
- (void) firstRun {
    if (((AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).firstRun)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Obviously, change `AppDelegate` to match the name of your app delegate class.

Comment: @Flz'Zen thank you for your reply. Will you be so kind to provide a bit of examle code. I'm not sure I comprehend all you wrote.

Comment: Still a problem, as stated it is a firstRun method. So a View is shown at first run. By tapping the home button, remove the app from the "Multitask bar", starting the app again the main View is shown. Short:the firstRun action (a disclaimer) is skipped. Any suggestions?

Comment: So you want to show the blue view the every time the app is launched, but not when it is resumed?

Comment: If that's the case, then you shouldn't use the defaults stuff at all because that persists the values after the application is shut down. Instead, set `self.firstRun = YES` on appDidFinishLaunching and set it to `NO` in `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application`.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. Case is this: I want to present the user with a firstRun screen with a disclamer and important info. On this screen is an Accept button to remove this screen and go to the "real" app screen. When declined by tapping the home button the app still persist in the MultiTask bar. When removed from this bar and launching the app again the firstRun screen is not shown but the "real" app screen appears. I need the user to tap the Accept button.(Sorry, I'm new to this so I head to ask a question about dismissing the view after tapping the Accept button as well)

Comment: Ok, in that case, you'll want to set the `firstRun` in defaults when the user presses Accept. This way, if the app is terminated before they accept and is launched again, `firstRun` won't be present in defaults. You may want to consider naming `firstRun` something more meaningful, such as `disclaimerAccepted`.

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna try to work that out in code. Great excersize. Thank you very much for all your trouble and maybe (stupid as I am) till later on this topic.